# React executes CATCH statement of PROMISE even after SUCCESS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am usually an angular developer and am working in react. Please excuse if this question seems simple.

I have a simple PROMISE

```
    return axios(`team/${this.state.teamId}/player`, this.state)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('formSubmit success');

            this.store.dispatch({
                type:       constants.PLAYER_UPDATE,
                payload:    response.data.user,
            });
            return false;

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error', error.response.data);
            this.setState({
                saveStatus: error.response.data.message
            });
            return Promise.reject(error)
        });
```

In the network tab I can see that URL fetched fine.
Also `store.dispatch` is called as it is printed in console.

But at same time it is calling code in the catch statement.
My console output is

```
formSubmit success                    Player.js:127
Store BEFORE | PLAYER_UPDATE          Store.js:76

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
at Player.js:135
```

Why is it going after CATCH() when everything is success? I even added return statement at the end of `this.store.dispatch`

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `catch` function will catch any error which will come in the `then`, if you want to just catch the error in promise, you probably want to use the second callback in `then` function. You should do something like this:

```
return axios.get(`endpoint`)
   .then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

OR, in your case,

```
return axios(`team/${this.state.teamId}/player`, this.state)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('formSubmit success');

            this.store.dispatch({
                type:       constants.PLAYER_UPDATE,
                payload:    response.data.user,
            });
            return false;

        }, (error) => {
            console.error('Error', error.response.data);
            this.setState({
                saveStatus: error.response.data.message
            });
            return Promise.reject(error)
        });
```

Comment: May be my brackets got messed up and i didnt notice. But that was my intention. Thanks for replying. Let me change code and try.

Comment: how to achieve success and failure callbacks with await ? I want to handle 401 and 403